# Nginx: неправильный mime type css-файла

Tags: html, css, nginx, mime

Необходимо на nginx балансировщике сделать собственные страницы ошибок. Страницы свёрстаны на html, css и с использованием логотипа нашей организации в формате jpg. Настроен nginx конфиг:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;
        location / {
                return 503;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location /500.html {
                root /var/www/html/nginx;
        }
}
```

Страница отдаётся, но проблема, что css файл и изображения отдаются с неправильным mime типом из-за чего страница отображается без каких-либо стилей и изображений:

[image: Неправильный mime type]

В конфиге mime.types nginx типы указаны верно. Подскажите в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Проблема у вас в том, что вы запретили всё (в том числе CSS), кроме `/500.html`

Comment: @AlexeyTen , то есть через слеш после html нужно дописать и необходимый css?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте такой конфиг

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testsite.ru www.testsite.ru;
    root /var/www/html/nginx;

    location / {
        return 503;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;

    location /500.html {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы root /var/www/html/nginx перенесли из локейшина html? Ведь этой директивой я указываю в какой директории лежит моя страница ошибок

Comment: чисто машинально, если у вас там файлы только для страниц с ошибками то да ее нужно вернуть в описание location